# Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Sometimes I can't start my Android emulator from Android Studio IDE. After examining idea.log file I found two reasons that brings the same error code:

**Missing quickbootChoice.ini file**

```
2023-07-13 15:06:58,427 [  51626]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-07-13 15:06:58,427 [  51626]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Found systemPath C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\
2023-07-13 15:06:58,527 [  51726]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\g\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-07-13 15:07:01,553 [  54752]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
2023-07-13 15:07:01,555 [  54754] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel XL API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
```

**Unable to determine if emulator is online**

```
2023-07-13 15:41:38,187 [2131386]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 is online, assuming it's not
2023-07-13 15:41:41,584 [2134783]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
2023-07-13 15:41:41,584 [2134783] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 2 API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740940
```

What is quickbootChoice.ini file and why it sometimes becomes missing?